Laravel start a web session from sanctum auth
I am developing a mobile app using laravel as backend for APIs but I need some auth pages of the web to be directly accessible from app, therefore I implemented the below middleware to check auth or auth:sanctum
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
{
    if (Auth::guard('web')->check()) {
        // Session-based authentication successful
        return $next($request);
    } elseif (Auth::guard('sanctum')->check()) {
        // Token-based authentication successful
        Auth::shouldUse('sanctum');
        if (session('id') == null) {
            session()->start();
            $request->session()->regenerate();
        }
        return $next($request);
    } else {
        if ($request->is('api/*') || $request->wantsJson() || $request->hasHeader('Authorization')) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }
        // Neither authentication passed
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }
}

The datatable is failing to load because the ajax loading the datatable does not have any auth. How can fix that? I have implemented a session initiation logic above however it is not working.

I cannot comment so i am gonna answer directly here.
SESSION vs TOKEN
When using session each authenticated users has a session attached to it containing data related to that user, this is why you can use something like auth()->user() for example.
Meanwhile when using token based authentication each authenticated user has a access token which must be sent with each request to authenticate the user.
To conclude there's no session when using sanctum, and when building api server make sure to set guards to api inside config/auth.php.
